# NSMutableData to const uint8

Tags: objective-c

I have strange issue

Server sending function

```
-(void) writeToServer:(const uint8_t *) buf {
    NSLog(@"sending buf %s with lenght %zd", buf, strlen((char*)buf));
    [oStream write:buf maxLength:strlen((char*)buf)]; 
     // NSOutputStream *oStream
}
```

`buf` is

```
NSLog(@"converted %@ length %d", encrypted, [encrypted length]);
// encrypted is NSMutableData
return (const uint8_t*)[encrypted bytes];
```

Output

```
 converted <4b010000 00000006 00000000 00000f20 30303031 4e50> length 22
 sending buf K with lenght 2
```

I need buf to remain the same.. with same raw bytes and proper lenght, how should i do that?

Comment: it is NSOutputStream *oStream;

Comment: what are you sending? C string or raw data?

Comment: I would like to send raw data

Comment: then why you use %s and strlen? they only works with C string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `NSData` object in directly:

```
-(void)writeToServer:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"sending with length %lu", (unsigned long)[data length]);
    [oStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]]; 
}
```